# Binding.scala route redirecting to login page

Tags: scala, binding.scala

I would like add "guards" to certain urls. These urls should only be accessed when the user is logged in. If not logged in i want to redirect the user to the login page. After a successful login i want the user to be "redirected" to the original hash.

This is my router

```
@dom
def outlet: Binding[Node] = {
    <div>{
    route.state.bind match {
        case s: View if UserService.hasRole("admin") => s.render.bind
        case s  if !UserService.isLoggedIn() => loginPage.render(Some(s.hash)).bind
        case _ => <div>Unknown</div>
    }
    }</div>
```

The `loginPage` then changes the window hash after a successful login:

```scala
def login(username: String, password:String, orginalHash: Option[String]) =
    UserService.login(username,password).andThen{
        case Success(v) =>
            println(s"changing hash to $orginalHash")
            orginalHash.map(_.substring(1)).foreach(window.location.hash=_)
        case Failure(e) => message.value = "Wrong username/password"
    }
```

However i guess because the hash in fact does not change, it does not update the page:

- Say i go to `/index.html/#/foobar`
- The "guard" kicks in and the login page is shown (url remains `/index.html/#/foobar`)
- Value of the `orginalHash` is `#/foobar`
- changing the `location.hash` to `/foobar` does nothing

Is there a way to manipulate the router. Is there perhaps an api to change the current page?

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a data-binding application, however some mutable states are not bindable in your system.

You should make `UserService.isLoggedIn` and `UserService.hasRole("admin")` be bindable.

Comment: tried making a `val user: Var[Option[User]]` and change its value while using it in the pattern match guards , but does not help. I might just use a url query string instead.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to directions from @yang-bo i solved it by using a `val user: Var[Option[User]]` inside `UserService` and changing the pattern match to

```scala
@dom
def outlet: Binding[Node] = {
    <div>{
        (route.state.bind, UserService.user.bind) match {
        case (s: View, Some(_))  => s.render.bind
        case (s, None) => loginPage.render(Some(s.hash)).bind
        case (_,_) => <div>Unknown</div>
    }
    }</div>
}
```